# what owner of schema can do that regular user with permission can not do?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I create a schema and set schema owner on it.

1. what the owner can do as owner that a user with permission can't do?
2. why the schema need owner?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2?

Comment: What permissions are you comparing against? For instance most systems have a level of super user that bypasses any restrictions, including those that might care about the owner.

Comment: While posting a SQL related question; do clarify which RDBMS you are using? So that, people can provide an exact answer.

Comment: sql server 2012 , my qustion is which opration the owner can do? thay reguler user with permmision on sechame can not do?

Answer (score 0):

Unless designed by means of permissions being in place, by default there is little difference. I.e. on a stock SQL Server installation, the owner and a regular user would have similar permissions set up. The difference being that the owner cannot be dropped from the database, and normal users cannot revoke permissions or privileges from an owner.

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/ownership-and-user-schema-separation-in-sql-server):

> You cannot remove privileges from an object owner, and you cannot drop
>   users from a database if they own objects in it.

Things get more interesting once specific permissions have been set up, though. Imagine normal users are denied permission to read data from tables. The owner in that case would be able to see the data in table, while regular users would not.